# В Ubuntu 14.04, место нахождения, файла с информацией об устройствах USB конкретное?

Tags: ubuntu, usb

В /sys/bus/usb/ подходящего нет.

Comment: пожалуйста: `$ lsusb`

Comment: Нужно программу не вызывать вы пропустили (операция затратная)

Comment: Как вы хотите прочитать информацию на интерфейсах не обращаясь к ним, поясните?